# Expressing units of time

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, time-series, stopping-times

How would you express 8/3 seconds as time after 3pm ?

8/3 = 2.66666

0.66*60 =40 miliseconds = 0.04 seconds

so 2.04 seconds after 3

3:00:02:04 pm ?

Is this correct?

Comment: 0.66 sec is not 40 milliseconds!! "milli" means $10^{-3}$. and $1millisecond = 10^{-3}seconds$

Comment: Just put in the seconds as decimal, i.e. 3:00:02.67 pm

Comment: mmm, are you sure you don't multiply by 60? 

because 2.50  minutes 

i would do 0.50 * 60 = 30 so i would write as 2 minutes and 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

An argument could be made that 3:00:02:40 is a correct answer.  That is, the colon, which is standard in expressing time in hours:minutes:seconds, can be interpreted as indicating sexagesimal notation, in which case $8/3=2+(40/60)$ gives the final 02:40.  But I don't know of anyone who expresses time this way.  If you look, for example, at [Michael Phelps's world records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Phelps#World_records), you see the fractions of a second portion given in decimal form, e.g., 1:54.92 for the 200m butterfly.

In any event, 3:00:02:04 is definitely not correct.

Comment: so 2.66 seconds = 2.40 -- is it read as 2 seconds and 40 milliseconds?

Comment: @confused, no!  I am suggesting that you *could* possibly use a *colon* to indicate sexagesimal notation and write 2:40 for the decimal time 2.666666.....

Comment: but if 2.66 is 2.66 seconds, what do you say for 2.40 (how do you say this?)